# C++ unordered_set hash function fail if using user defined struct

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, hashset

I have a question that is blowing my mind related to C++ unordered_set hash function. Here is the code.

```
typedef struct chess{
    vector<pair<int,int>> *b_chess;              // pointer to boxes coordinates

    bool operator==(const  chess& b) const{
        if (b_chess->size() != b.b_chess->size()) {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<b_chess->size();i++){
            if( (*b_chess)[i] != (*b.b_chess)[i] ) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
} chess;

struct chess_hash{
    size_t operator()(const chess &b) const{
        size_t x_value, y_value,hash_value ;
        for(ll i = 0; i< b.b_chess->size();i++){
            x_value += (*b.b_chess)[i].first * i;
            y_value += (*b.b_chess)[i].second * i;
        }
        hash<size_t> hash_ll;
        hash_value = size_t(x_value+y_value);
        return hash_value;
    }
};

int main(){
    vector<pair<int,int>> v = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
    vector<pair<int,int>> *v1 = new vector<pair<int,int>> (v);
    vector<pair<int,int>> *v2 = new vector<pair<int,int>> (*v1);
    chess c1;
    chess c2;
    c1.b_chess = v1;
    c2.b_chess = v2;
    unordered_set<chess, chess_hash> s1;
    unordered_set<chess, chess_hash>::hasher fn = s1.hash_function();
    cout << "c1's hashvalue " << fn(c1) <<" c2's hashvalue "<< fn(c2) << endl;     //  two hashvalues are different
    if( c1 == c2) cout <<"SAME data\n";      // This line will print same data

    s1.insert(c1);
    if(s1.count(c1)){
        cout <<"Found chess\n";               // it won't go there
    }
}
```

In the main function, I have a vector of pairs (coordinates of boxes) and I have two user-defined structs chess pointing to their corresponding data.

**The program result is:**

c1's hashvalue 6422192 c2's hashvalue 1878014541

SAME data

**Another case:**

If I define a function go_hash(const chess &b)

```
    size_t go_hash(const chess &b) const{
        size_t x_value, y_value,hash_value ;
        for(size_t i = 0; i< b.b_chess->size();i++){
            x_value += (*b.b_chess)[i].first * i;
            y_value += (*b.b_chess)[i].second * i;
        }
        hash<size_t> hash_ll;
        hash_value = hash_ll(x_value+y_value);
        return hash_value;
    }
```

go_hash(c1) will return the same hash value as go_hash(c2)

I don't understand why two pieces of code yield different results. Is there something else unordered_set as a STL is doing that I am missing? I provide a hash function and an operator== overload function. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be that you're not initializing your variables `x_value` and  `y_value` in `chess_hash::operator()`/`go_hash`; note that C++ does not 0 initialize integer variables like these.
This makes your hash function return non-deterministic values, giving you different results even on the same input data.

I'd recommend to turn on compiler warnings (`-Wall`), mistakes like that are usually caught by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks so much! I thought there is something stl is implementing that I missed lol. BTW, just tested, adding -Wall flag does not catch this mistake.

Comment: g++ doesn't, which is a shame. But fortunately clang does.